# Append XSL tags to HTML DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

If I have an empty XSL doc as follows:

```
<body>
   <div id="myList">

   </div>
</body>
```

How can I access the div tag and append XSL to it? For example, I want to do the following in my js code but it doesn't output anything. But if I manually insert the innerHTML value into the div tag it works:

```
document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML = `<xsl:value-of select="Movies/Authors/FirstName"/>`
```

I've tried using different quote styles but I can't seem to get the expected output. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You are trying to apply a XML style language to HTML?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to auto-generate an XSL stylesheet through javascript by appending DOM elements to an empty XSL doc.

Comment: XSL is a stylesheet for XML so I'm having trouble understanding this.

Comment: Yes, XSL is a stylesheet but it is similar to HTML in that it has DOM elements with tags (i.e. <xsl:value of ...>, <xsl:for-each of...>. Is there any way to append these to an XSL sheet by accessing their outer HTML elements and changing the innerHTML?

Comment: Consider to edit your question and provide a minimal but complete code snippet allowing us to reproduce the problem. Currently is not clear what kind of document you have and why you consider something like the snippet you have posted an XSL doc that is empty. An empty XSLT stylesheet is rather `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"></xsl:stylesheet>` and you could parse that with client-side Javascript using DOMParser or XMLHttpRequest into an XML DOM document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an XSLT stylesheet as an XML DOM document and a recent version of a browser supporting `innerHTML` on XML elements (I have tested successfully with current versions of Chrome, Firefox and Edge on Windows 10 Creators Update) you can use e.g.

```js
var xslString = `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="Root">
   <div id="myList">

   </div>  
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>`;

var xmlString = `<Root>
  <Movies>
     <Authors>
       <FirstName>Steven</FirstName>
     </Authors>
  </Movies>
</Root>`;

var domParser = new DOMParser();

var xsltDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xslString, 'application/xml');

var xmlDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'application/xml');

var div = xsltDoc.querySelector('#myList');

div.innerHTML = `<xsl:value-of select="Movies/Authors/FirstName"/>`;

var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
proc.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);

document.getElementById('result').appendChild(proc.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document));
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Result</h1>
  <div id="result"></div>
</section>
```